# How to get name of the function

Tags: function, lua

I have a problem. How to know the name of the function that called my function without using the debug namespace. For example:

```
function test1()
   test2()
end

function test2()
   --How to get here name of function which have called my function test2.
   --How to get here "test1"?
end
```

It's will be easy if I will be allow to use debug namespace, but I can use. Have anyone any idea?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 5):

Functions do not have names. Functions are values in Lua, just like the number `5.23`, or the string `"string"`. Those are values, and they can be stored in many places. Therefore, there is no real name for a function. The Debug system assigns functions names based on how they were initially declared, but that's about it.

If a function needs to know who called it, then it is the responsibility of that function to take the caller as a function parameter.

Comment: Interesting idea, but there are a lot function, which call test2(). I have found about 50 files, and each file have 2-5 calls. It will take a lot of time, to change

Comment: @user1274868: Well, you have two choices: either change all of those calls, or do without. What you want is *not possible*. Not without the debug library, and even then, only some functions have names in that.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. I will make a script< which will replace all call of the function test2() on call test2("module_name")

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve half of your problem, but you *can* give your functions names with [FuncTables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FuncTables). Whether you can use this to help solve your problem, I don't know.

```
-- create a functable --

functable = {name = "bob"}
metatable = {}

metatable.__call = function()
    print "you just called a table!"
end

setmetatable(functable,metatable)

-- call a functable and get it's name --

functable()
print(functable.name)
```